# What is "not serializable" in this Groovy method?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I wrote the following function which is loaded to my pipeline:

```
def userTrigger() {
  [$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: jenkins_creds, usernameVariable: 'J_USER', passwordVariable: 'J_PASS'],
  ]){
      cmd = "curl -s -u \${J_USER}:\${J_PASS} \${env.BUILD_URL}api/json | python -mjson.tool | grep userId | awk '{print \$2}' | tr -d '"|,' "
      def ut = sh(returnStdout: true, script: cmd)
      return ut
    }
}
```

The result should be the username of the one who triggered the build, before cleaning the output it looks like so:

```
"userId": "itaig",
```

Basically, this:

```
awk -F'"' '{print $4}'
```

would also give me the required output but i'm not sure how to escape chars in this statement too.

When I run the job, I get the following error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
```

I'm pretty much sure it has something to do with my tries of escaping the relevant characters but I have a feeling that I haven't done it right, I've tried escaping the (") in the end of the cmd line but to no avail.

Can you try and find my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is that right parenthesis and right bracket closing on line #3?

```
]){
```

It might be more of the double-quote vs single-quote then the escaping of characters - make sure they are are pairing up nicely.

Comment: That's the way to use the UsernamePasswordMultiBinding class, I'm using it in order to be able to inject jenkins username and password to the curl command as masked values.

Comment: You can see it here: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204897020-Fetch-a-userid-and-password-from-a-Credential-object-in-a-Pipeline-job-?mobile_site=true

Comment: @ItaiGanot - In the examples in your link all the brackets are "balanced", but the example in your question the brackets are "unbalanced".  After I counted manually (start at zero +1 for a left, -1 for a right) the examples and a couple of the samples - only your posted answer is unbalanced.  I double-checked using Notepad++ plugin "BracketsCheck" and all the examples from the linked page pass - and the example code in your question fails as "unbalanced".  I count 1 left bracket and 2 right brackets.  Don't think I can be of much help beyond that :-).